# Show Espresso test result on console

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I am running espresso from command line via gradle (in our ci). It logs failed tests to the command line. So far so good but is there a way to make espresso log successful tests as well?

Answer (score -1):

Running `connectedDebugAndroidTest` with `--stacktrace` and `--info`:

```
./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest --stacktrace --info
```

would yield following output in console:

[image]

Comment: I tried --info too but it logs so much stuff that travis-ci assumes it to be in an endless loop and kills the process

Comment: Then problem delegates to "how to make Travis not to kill that process?", because it is not connected with instrumented tests whatsoever.

Comment: but the amount of output also makes it very hard to find the test results at all. I only mentioned the travis killing the process to illustrate the amount of output